# Dante server high CPU% load and negotiation process

Tags: ubuntu, process, dante

I am a noobie trying to figure out a way to host proxies for my family and friends (around 20 people maybe) for Telegram. I am using a DigitalOcean droplet with 2vCPU and the rest are base configurations. Below is my server config. I run it on the specific port which is open in the firewall, and there are no issues connecting. However, when Dante creates new  processes named "negotiation" (or something like that), they stay alive for more than 30 (default timeout time). And the overall status looks like on the picture below. I am clueless on what could be the problem. Thanks you in advance!

````
user.unprivileged: nobody
#logoutput: /var/log/danted.log

# The listening network interface or address.
internal: eth0 port=3785

# The proxying network interface or address.
external: eth0

# socks-rules determine what is proxied through the external interface.
socksmethod: username

# client-rules determine who can connect to the internal interface.
clientmethod: none

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
   #log: connect disconnect error ioop
}

client block {
    from: 0/0 to: 0/0
    #log: connect disconnect error ioop
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    #log: connect disconnect error ioop
    user: tsecret
}

socks block {
    from: 0/0 to: 0/0
}```


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic3J8.png
````

Comment: What do logs show? Can you capture traffic using tcpdump while you run test, or run Dante in debug mode? Further tests may help you understand what's going on.